# Can I use PICkit 3 to program an ATF16V8CZ?

Tags: programmable-logic, pickit, pld

Is possible to program an ATF16V8CZ chip using a PICkit 3 programmer?

In the pin description of the datasheet I can't find the conections to the programmer or the MCLR pin.

Comment: PICkit programmers are for Microcontrollers. Your ATF16V8 is a PLD - it doesn't have an MCLR pin or any of the other in-circuit programming features of PIC microcontrollers.

Comment: No. The Pickit3 doesn't have enough I/O pins to program GALs. You can do it with an Arduino https://github.com/ole00/afterburner

Comment: @BruceAbbott unfortunately that link also mentions explicitly that AT16V8CZ's are not supported. There are affordable commercial device programmers on the market that still support these devices though.

Comment: @StarCat I noticed that. Not sure what the problem is since I was able to program them fine with my device. Might need to look my code to see what I did that they aren't doing. IIRC it was just 1 bit that had to be set in the fusemap.